# WiX Changing UI items based on OS version

Tags: wix, installation, windows-installer, windowsversion

I have created an installer for my application, now my requirement is to customise UI items like some check boxes based on OS version(need to have slightly different UI for Windows 8 and Windows 10). How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Basically you add a condition in the control element based on a property like VersionNT or VersionNT64. The answer here has control conditions of the type you can use:

[WIX radio button group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17198443/wix-radio-button-group)