# 'Remember Property' pattern and the property used in RadioButtonGroup

Tags: wix

I'm trying to save the property value in registry during setup and read it next time installation is run. 
I follow 'Remember property' pattern as described [here](http://robmensching.com/blog/posts/2010/5/2/the-wix-toolsets-remember-property-pattern/)

It basically works as expected, but I cannot get one scenario working:

- I run setup (property gets stored in the registry)
- I run setup again without entering property value on command line
- I expect value of the property to be read from registry, but it is assigned default value.

I think, I know where is the problem: I have "Value" assigned to the property, while the example I've mentioned above, declares "remembered" property without "Value". In my package, I have to define the value as I use the property in UI element with RadioButtonGroup. If I don't declare Value field of the property, I get compilation error:

```
 error LGHT0204 : ICE34: Property LOCATION (of RadioButtonGroup control LocationSelection.InstallationLocation) is not defined in the Property Table.
```

Can anybody give me a hint how to manage it?

Comment: You should post your code. If you did actually declare the property then it will be in the Property table. It appears that you may have mis-declared it somehow.

Comment: Negative. I have property declared with 'Value="something"' - then the package compiles and works as expected (except the issue I ask about). It is enough to remove Value tag from property declaration: and you get ICE34. I guess assigning Value to property is mandatory for using it together with RadioButtonGroup.  And this breaks reading defaults.

Comment: OK - I solved it finally using 3 properties: one for reading/storing permanent value from/to registry, second - for getting value from command-line during silent install and third - "effective" value, that is used with RadioButtonGroup. First two properties does not have default value assigned, while "effective" one - does. Then, with CustomActions, I can asign "effective" property according to values from command-line and registry.

Answer (score 2):

Here is solution draft:

Custom actions to fill properties

```
<CustomAction Id='SaveCmdLineValueLocation' Property='CMDLINE_LOCATION'
              Value='[LOCATION]' Execute='firstSequence' />
<CustomAction Id='SetFromCmdLineValueLocation' Property="EFFECTIVE_LOCATION"
              Value='[CMDLINE_LOCATION]' Execute='firstSequence' />
<CustomAction Id='SetFromRegValueLocation' Property="EFFECTIVE_LOCATION"
              Value='[REG_LOCATION]' Execute='firstSequence' />
```

Execute sequence that assignes EFFECTIVE_LOCATION either from registry or msiexec command line:

```
<InstallExecuteSequence>
      <Custom Action='SaveCmdLineValueLocation' Before='AppSearch'>
        LOCATION
      </Custom>      
      <Custom Action='SetFromCmdLineValueLocation' After='AppSearch'>
        CMDLINE_LOCATION
      </Custom>
      <Custom Action='SetFromRegValueLocation' After='AppSearch'>
        REG_LOCATION AND (NOT CMDLINE_LOCATION)
      </Custom>
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

Properties declaration:

```
<!-- Property used on command-line. -->
<Property Id="LOCATION" Secure="yes">
</Property>

<!-- Property used finally with ReadioButtonGroup. It must have Value assigned (required when used with RadioButtonGroup -->
<Property Id="EFFECTIVE_LOCATION" Value="OFFICE" Secure="yes">
</Property>

<!-- Read previous value from registy (from recent installation) -->
<Property Id="REG_LOCATION" Secure="yes">
  <RegistrySearch Id="loc" Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\Company\Product" Type="raw" Name="LOCATION"  Win64='yes'>
  </RegistrySearch>
</Property>
```

Comment: Works nicely. Thanks a lot.